# htaccess not updating after CSP changes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, content-security-policy

I have the following directory paths:

```
www/.htaccess
www/club/.htaccess
www/club/downloads/.htaccess
```

In www .htaccess I have:
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' *.mydomain"

And...originally in club htaccess I had the following CSP:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' *.mydomain"
```

I then updated club .htaccess that CSP to:

```
SetEnvIf X-Requested-With "com.myapp" isMyapp
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' google.com *.mydomain" env=!isMyapp
```

And in downloads .htaccess I updated a CSP to:

```
SetEnvIf X-Requested-With "com.myapp" isMyapp
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' microsoft.com *.mydomain" env=!isMyapp
```

However, in my app, everytime it makes a request to my server its denied because of the original CSP.  But in the refused message, it only lists `*.mydomain.com` as a part of the policy thats causing it to be rejected.  So I added google.com and microsoft.com to the CSPs to see if it shows up in the `Refused` message.  But it continues to only list `*.mydomain.com` and it never updates.

I cleared the app cache, reinstalled the app - but the CSP being served by the .htaccess files is never being updated.  I have read that apache is supposed to read .htaccess from each folder/sub-folder on every request - but if thats the case, why is my app still seeing the old CSP and not seeing the new one(s)?

## UPDATE:

In the root www htaccess, I updated the CSP to:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' *.yahoo.com *.mydomain"
```

And now when my app accesses my website it works and the CSP in the Request Response Headers is showing the *.yahoo.com.

Soooo....now the question is why isn't the www/club/.htaccess or even the www/club/downloads.htaccess overriding the parent htaccess files?

Comment: Multiple CSP would "add" to each other, with the strictest one winning in each case, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#multiple_content_security_policies Only with `Header set`, the header should be overwritten. Since that does not appear to be happening here - I am guessing your `isMyapp` condition is probably not working as it should?

Comment: @CBroe - ah, I think you are saying `Header set` should override the parent, but `Header always set` makes the parent the preferred CSP?  Is this correct?

Comment: No, `Header set` alone should overwrite the header already. `always` only specifies that this header should also be issued in case the request gets answered with an error status code. What I am saying is that your Header in club/.htaccess probably did not overwrite the header from the upper level to begin with, because your _condition_ might not actually be fulfilled (talking about the `env=!isMyapp` part here.)

Comment: Did you not get that condition the wrong way around? You want to add this header when it _is_ your app that is making the request, no?

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation.  Let me look at the logic again.  For `frame-anscestors`, my goal is to have only my domain and my app allow access to these specific subdirectories....and reject all others.  But, because I can't add `com.myapp` (which is the app origin) as a legitimate domain,  I have to say `allow frame-ancestors for mydomain.com when env !='com.myapp'` - which should apply the rule to every browser or app except when my app is making the call; which then would allow my app to use iFrames, but none others.